# How to convert csv to datatable in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, datatable

I'm converting .csv file to datatable like below.

```
string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";
            string itinerarycsvfilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"D:\projects\MSC cruise\MSCCruiseProjects\MsccruiseWithLogin\MsccruiseWithLogin\UnzippedFiles\itinff_gbr_eng.csv");
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(@"D:\projects\MSC cruise\MSCCruiseProjects\MsccruiseWithLogin\MsccruiseWithLogin\UnzippedFiles\itinff_gbr_eng.csv");
            string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + filename + "]";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + itinerarycsvfilePath +
              ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("ItineraryDetails");
                dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                return dataTable;
            }
```

then the result when I look with quick watch[image]

- Am I doing something wrong.I feel like that because table does not show like columns.
  what can I do for that.
  hope your help.

Answer (score 0):

See code below

```
    public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice, I got the same result from my code also.I'm wondering why it didn't show like a table.that means with rows and columns @jdweng

Comment: Using quick watch you need to look at DataTable - Rows.  You have db in watch which is the data returned from OleDbAdapter.  Never used with watch.

Comment: so what can I do @jdweng

Comment: The results may be correct, just the watch isn't working.  I usually just verify results by putting DataTable into a DataGridView.

Comment: how can I do that with this.hope your help

Comment: DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.  Since you are getting a DataSource you need to specify a table like ds.Tables[0] or equivalent.